# Error (Xcode): Framework not found TensorFlowLiteC

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, tensorflow, tflite

while running my flutter project on ios, got this error. I basically use tfilte_flutter for face detection. I am having Mac M2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download TensorFlowLiteC.framework files from that package. You can get all information [at pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter#ios)

Comment: i already copied the TensorFlowLiteC.framework folder to pub cache tflite package path and there in ios folder. After this do i have to run a command or something because its showing same thing even with this.

Comment: Have you unzipped the folder downloaded zip folder?